# bounded operator in Fourier series

Tags: fourier-analysis, operator-theory, fourier-series

let $\{\phi_k\}$ be a complete orthonormal system in $L^2$. let $m=\{m_k\}$ be a sequence and let $f\in L^2$, $f\sim \sum c_k\phi_k$.

define an oparator $T$ by $Tf\sim \sum m_k c_k \phi_k$. then, show that

$m\in l^\infty\iff \exists c:const$ s.t. $||Tf||_{L^2} \leq c||f||_{L^2}$ $\forall f\in L^2$,

in particular, the smallest $c$ is $||m||_{l^\infty}$.

I could only show $\implies$ by letting $c=||m||_{l^\infty}$, but have no clue about the other parts.

any hints will be appriciated!

Comment: If $|m_k|$ is unbounded then you can find $c_k$ such that $\sum_k |c_k|^2  < \infty$ and $\sum_k |m_k c_k|^2= \infty$.

Comment: @user1952009 if $c_k$ decays much faster than $m_k$ growing, then isn't it possible $\sum|m_k c_k|^2<\infty$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that 
$$\tag{1}
|m_k|=\|T\phi_k\|_2.
$$
Then 
$$
|m_k|=\|T\phi_k\|_2\leq c\|\phi_k\|_2=c. 
$$
So $m\in\ell^\infty$ and $\|m\|\leq c$.

It might help to understand what needs to be done if you work in $\ell^2$ instead of $L^2$ (those two are isomorphic via 
$$
(x_k)\longmapsto \sum_kx_k\,\phi_k.
$$

Comment: I never noticed that $\phi_k$ is also in $L^2$ lol thank you so much!